# Firebase notifications error on Xcode thread 1 SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-notifications

I create an app with the Ionic Framework.

On iOS / Xcode: I have an error that appear when I build (with succeed) my app on Xcode.

This error is on the main.m:

> "Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT"

Where did this error come from? How to resolve it?

In my all exceptions breakpoint "objc_exception_throw in libobjc.A.dylib" and "_cxa_thrpw in libc++abi.dylib"

This breakpoint emphasizes the line "FIRApp configure]; " in my AppDelegate+FirebasePlugin.m

[Screen of Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGd4Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add GoogleService-Info.plist file to your project or does your file have different name than above?

If your file has different name then :

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: yourFileName ofType:@"plist"];
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused by GoogleService-Info.plist because it was empty.